# Print the default goal when no goal is passed

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

I have this following very simple makefile snippet:

```
# Set the default goal to build.
.DEFAULT_GOAL = build
$(info BUILD GOALS: $(MAKECMDGOALS))

.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo testing

.PHONY: build
build:
    @echo building
```

When I call `make` with no parameters (no goals), then the default goal should be `build` - which is does appear to be (i.e. build gets called and not test even though test is the first target).

The (very minor) issue I have is that I want to print the current GOAL. So I tried with MAKECMDGOALS, but it just prints an empty value. If I call `make build` or `make test` then MAKECMDGOALS shows the relevant value... but I want to show the build goal when it is using the default one as well. Note: I don't just want to print it in the target rule - since in my real makefile I have lots of these, I just want to print the current GOAL using makefile $(info ...) or some such.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just print `.DEFAULT_GOAL`?

```
$(info BUILD GOALS: $(or $(MAKECMDGOALS),$(.DEFAULT_GOAL)))
```